# SAPUI5 table formatting

Tags: css, sapui5

I am quite new in CSS and SAPUI5. Although making good progress, I am having a hard time applying style options to SAPUI5 tables. My action is aiming on formating a specific table having id tbl1. In index.html, I gave custom css style definition like:

```
#tbl1{
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#tbl1 tr{
    font-size: 150%;
    background: green;
}
```

That changed table header font size and background of cells but not the font size within the cells...
What's the best way to do so?

To give u an outlook on what I eventually want to achive:
Besides changing font size of rows and headers

- every second row should be colored what is already working using

  ```
  #tbl1 tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #DCDCDC;
  }
  ```
- dedicated cells should be colored depending on their values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SAPUI5 it is best practice to attach CSS classes to your controls. Unfortunately you can´t rely on the ID´s you assign to your controls for manual CSS-styling since the ID´s are not always assigned to the control you expect and sometimes ID´s are assigned relative to your view name e.g. in case of reusable views.

Let´s assume you have a table and content you want to apply CSS to:

```
var table = new sap.m.Table();
table.addStyleClass("myCustomTable");
```

And your Stylesheet could look like this:

```
.myCustomTable {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You can attach CSS classes to your `columns` and `items` aggregations as well which reflects `<th>` and `<tr>` styles.